# how to remove part of words from MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

select ename, email, +showing only the site from email(ex. if email is asd.gmail.com only 'gmail')
    from emp77

so basically I want to show ename, email, and the site from email

Comment: You can't simply select the whole email and then manipulate the result in (say) php to get the part you need?

Comment: try to locate the start point of `@` symbol, for name is everything before `@`, for site is everything after it and before `.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use combination of `substr`, `instr` and `substring_index`:

```
select ename,
    email,
    substring_index(
        substr(
            email, instr(email, '@') + 1
        ), '.', 1
    ) as email_domain
from emp77
```

Or using just substring_index twice, as suggested by @spencer7593 in the comments below:

```
select ename,
    email,
    substring_index(
        substring_index(email, '@', - 1)
        , '.', 1
    ) as email_domain
from emp77
```

Comment: or **`SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(email,'@',-1),'.',1)`**

Comment: @spencer7593 - Cool solution. Added it to answer. Thanks.